# log4j not loading custom properties config

Tags: java, logging, path, log4j, config

I'm trying to start up a java application from command line with the hope that it'll pick up the log4j config files in a different folder. Here is my folder structure:

- `/app`            -> app base folder
- `/app/config`     -> stores custom config files including log4j
- `/app/lib`        -> stores all the jars

However when I try running the program from `/app` for some reason log4j is not initializing properly:

```
-bash-4.2# pwd
/app
-bash-4.2# java -cp config:lib/* -Xmx1024M className
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger(org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Surprisingly, if I move the config folder to `/lib`, and then try to start up the java program from there, it all seems to be working:

(updated folder structure):

- `/app`            -> app base folder
- `/app/lib`        -> stores all the jars
- `/app/lib/config` -> stores custom config files including log4j

Output:

```
-bash-4.2# pwd
/app/lib
-bash-4.2# java -cp config:* -Xmx1024M className
<Expected log message now shows up>
```

Inside my code I used `PropertyConfigurator` to load the config file:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(loggingConfigFile)
```

Where `logProperties` is defined as

```
val loggingConfigFile = "config/custom.logging.properties"
```

Originally I thought the problem with the first scenario was with some kind of pathing issue, however when printing out `System.getProperty("user.dir")` during run time it seems that the program was indeed running under `/app` and that it should be able to load the config file from the defined path (i.e. `/app/config/custom.logging.properties`). Is there anything wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Application tries to find property files at run time path.

It's working in my case

[image]

For access properties value. Make ResourceBundle Object.
Ex.:

```
private final ResourceBundle objRbLdap = ResourceBundle.getBundle("prperties file name");
```